# Problem in computing residue

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I need to integrate the following function $F(y)$ of complex variable $y$ over the unit circle $|y|=1$:

```
F[y_]:=-(((-1 + q) (-1 + t) (-1 + q^2 t) (-q t + Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + 
   q t Sqrt[q/y]) (q t - y) (-1 + y)^2 (-1 + q t y) (-q t + 
   y Sqrt[q/y]) (-q - y + 2 y Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 - q y + 
   2 y Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + q t y Sqrt[q/y]))/(2 (1 + q) (q - t) (-1 +
    q t) (-q + Sqrt[q/y]) (-t + Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + 
   q  Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + t Sqrt[q/y]) (q - y) y^2 (-t + y) (-1 + 
   q y) (-1 + t y) (-q + y Sqrt[q/y]) (-t + y Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + 
   q y Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + t y  Sqrt[q/y])))
```

Here $q,t$ are also complex numbers with modulus $<1$. The idea is to use residue theorem. To that end, I compute the points of singularity to be `y=q/t^2,q^3,t^2 q,q,t,t^2/q,0`.

Using `Residue`, I get residues for all points except `y=0`. For `Residue[F[y],{y,0}]`, the output comes same as the input. I think the trouble there is because of the terms like `Sqrt[q/y]`. However doing the series expansion `Series[F[y],{y,0,2}]` around the point `y=0` to order `2`, I get

```
(-1 + q) (-1 + t) (-1 + q^2 t)/2 (1 + q) (q - t) (-1 + q t)
```

as the coefficient of the term `1/y`. I am confused on why `Residue` did not give me this output. From Hugh's comment below, I think I see that `y=0` is a branch point, so one needs to change the path of integration. However, I do not know how to tell mathematica to do this. Any input to that direction would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange! It is a good habit here to provide copyable Mathematica so that other users can copy and experiment with it.

Comment: I think that the square root means that you  have a branch cut starting at y = 0. There is thus a line of discontinuity radiating out from zero. You can't integrate by just looking at residues. You have to change your contour of integration to exclude the branch cut. There is no residue at y = 0. Are you clear on such matters?

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comment. I had not thought about the branch cut; I am doing this now.

Comment: You said there is no residue at $y=0$. However, doing the `Series` expansion around the point $0$, I get $\frac{(-1 + q) (-1 + t) (-1 + q^2 t)}{2 (1 + q) (q - t) (-1 + q t)}$ as the coefficient of the term $1/y$. Am I doing this wrong? Sadly, I don't seem to figure out how to tell mathematica to integrate the function, given that there is a branch point at $y=0$. Could you help me with that?

Comment: The input should be provided in cut-and-pastable form.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it's better now.

Comment: Correct code: `sqrt{q/y}` to `Sqrt[q/y]` and `ty` to `t y`

Comment: Thanks. (I was thinking in terms of latex :))

Comment: When you ask me a question it is best to start with an @Hugh. I then get a prompt in my in box. I just came back here wondering how you have got on.

Comment: The series expansion of 1/Sqrt[z] does not really exist (I think). If you just try it in Mathematica it gives you back 1/Sqrt[z] plus higher order terms.

Comment: True. But in my case, the singularity is because of the presence of `y^2= 0`, not `Sqrt[y]` in the denominator.

Comment: @Hugh, why do you say that there is no residue at `y=0`?

Comment: A branch point is not a residue. A residue is an isolated singularity but is surrounded by an analytic region. A branch point has a line of discontinuity passing away from the singularity. Thus you can't integrate around it; there is a jump as you go around.  What are typical (possible)  values of q and t and I will plot the discontinuity for you.

Comment: @Hugh, Thank you. q,t are complex numbers with modulus less than 1. (I forgot to address you in my previous comment, so doing this now to make sure to see this.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but just an extended comment to show how you can explore a function of a complex variable. Here is your function.

```
F[y_] := -(((-1 + q) (-1 + t) (-1 + q^2 t) (-q t + Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + 
        q t Sqrt[q/y]) (q t - y) (-1 + y)^2 (-1 + q t y) (-q t + 
        y Sqrt[q/y]) (-q - y + 2 y Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 - q y + 
        2 y Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + q t y Sqrt[q/y]))/(2 (1 + q) (q - 
        t) (-1 + q t) (-q + Sqrt[q/y]) (-t + Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + 
        q Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + t Sqrt[q/y]) (q - y) y^2 (-t + y) (-1 + 
        q y) (-1 + t y) (-q + y Sqrt[q/y]) (-t + y Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + 
        q y Sqrt[q/y]) (-1 + t y Sqrt[q/y])))
```

I start by giving values to q and t with your constraints and then solve to find the roots of the denominator (the poles). I prefer to work with complex variable z because I am traditional.

```
    f = F[z] /. {t -> (1 + I) 2, q -> (1 - I)/2};
den = Denominator[f // Together];
rts = Solve[den == 0, z]
```

This gives me

```
(* {{z -> -(1/4) - I/4}, {z -> -(1/16) - I/16}, {z -> 1/8 - I/8}, {z -> 
   1/4 - I/4}, {z -> 1/2 - I/2}, {z -> 1 + I}, {z -> 2 + 2 I}, {z -> 
   4 + 4 I}}  *)
```

A plot of the position of the roots is

```
Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[ReIm[z]] /. rts}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Quite a scatter.

I now plot the modulus of the function and put a pin in at each pole.

```
h = 2;
Show[
 Graphics3D[{
   Line[{Flatten@{ReIm[z], 0}, Flatten@{ReIm[z], 2 h}}] /. rts,
   Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[Flatten@{ReIm[z], 2 h}] /. rts},
  Axes -> True],
 Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[f /. z -> x + I y]], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, h}}, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Doing the same for the argument of the function

```
h = 2;
Show[
 Graphics3D[{
   Line[{Flatten@{ReIm[z], 0}, Flatten@{ReIm[z], 2 h}}] /. rts,
   Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[Flatten@{ReIm[z], 2 h}] /. rts},
  Axes -> True],
 Plot3D[Evaluate[Arg[f /. z -> x + I y]], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that there are surfaces which are discontinuous. One point for investigation is a peak at about -2 + 2 I which does not have a pin. Why?  Also I should be cautions about saying the roots of the denominator are poles. This is not a rational polynomial so these roots need checking. You could also look at roots of the numerator.

Overall you have something to explore. Further embellishments could be to make a dynamic plot where you could vary the location of t and q.

Have a good exploration. Hope that helps.